# Update array of object in React useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a class `ListItem` which is a list of `Item`. It got some function like `setItem` that update an item in the list and `addItem` that add an item and `filterItem` that set `visible`

`Item` is an object that looks like `{name,number,discount,visible}`

I have a view `ListItemView` with a pseudo code like this

```
export default function ListItemView() {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setItems(new ListItem(getItems()))
    }, [])
    
    function toggleChange(f,newF){
        setItems((current) => current.setItem(f,newF))
    }

    function filter(search){
        setItems(Items.filterItem({search}))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setItems(items.addItem())}> ADD Item</button>
            <input onChange={(e) => filter(e.target.value)} />
            {items.items.map((Item) =>
               !item.visible && item.visible !== undefined  ? null :
               <div key={Item.id}>
                  <ItemLine f={item} toggleChange={toggleChange} />
               </div>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

And `ItemLine` is just a component that display inputs with the datas of my item

**So there is my questions :**

- To update my items, am I forced to use `setItems` everytimes ? Because it's causing the full rerender of the page, that's quite dumb for me because when we are just setting 1 data in one object of an entire list ?
- My filter function is quick when I'm typing (to filter on my list), but it's pretty slow when I have to reshow every items in my list, with 300 items it would be unusable, how can I change this ?
- I have heard of ReactHook form, would it work for me here ?

Thanks for your expertise :)

Comment: "am I forced to use setItems everytimes" Yes, this is how React works. React is pretty optimized out-of-the-box and could easily handle rendering an array of a few hundred elements. Your `items` state is an array, what is the state updater doing to your state, i.e. what is `current.setItem(f,newF)`? You are mapping `items.items`, so now I'm thinking that your `items` state isn't actually an array and your mounting `useEffect` is mutating the state shape.

Comment: I have changed `items` initial state it should be `new ListItem()` but my mounting `useEffect` set `items` to `new ListItem(someitems)` where `someitems` is an array of items that I get from my database.
`current.setItem(f,newF)` will search `f` the old `item` in `items.items` and put `newF` which is the new item, for exemple a new name.

Maybe I should have show `ListItem` class but it's simply a class with `this.items` as state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To update my items, am I forced to use setItems everytimes ? Because
> it's causing the full rerender of the page, that's quite dumb for me
> because when we are just setting 1 data in one object of an entire
> list ?

Yes you need to call setItems to update your state even if it is to add one element or to update one.

However you can optimise on re-renders by converting your mapped values to components and using `React.memo` to avoid re-renders .

```
function Item = React.memo(({item, toggleChange}) => {
   return !item.visible && item.visible !== undefined  ? null :
        <div key={Item.id}>
                  <ItemLine f={item} toggleChange={toggleChange} />
         </div>
})
export default function ListItemView() {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setItems(new ListItem(getItems()))
    }, [])

    // using useCallback to have only one instaance of toggleChange being created even on re-renders 
    const toggleChange = useCallback(function toggleChange(f,newF){
        setItems((current) => current.setItem(f,newF))
    }, []);

    function filter(search){
        setItems(Items.filterItem({search}))
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setItems(items.addItem())}> ADD Item</button>
            <input onChange={(e) => filter(e.target.value)} />
            {items.items.map((Item) =>
               <Item key={item.id} item={item} toggleChange={toggleChange}/>
            )}
        </>
    )
}
```

> My filter function is quick when I'm typing (to filter on my list),
> but it's pretty slow when I have to reshow every items in my list,
> with 300 items it would be unusable, how can I change this ?

If you are rendering large lists, you should aim towards virtualising those, i.e rendering only items that are in the view. [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) and [`react-virtualized`](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) are popular libraries that you can explore for that.

Comment: If we are taking about performance for writing code in React, I don't know what is right and what is wrong in React , Just blindly believe maybe its ok!

Comment: @Nur It is important to try to the code implementation yourself and constantly profile in devtools to understand the impact. React also supports a profiler in latest version to help you with it.